# Recipe for target 'sizebefore' failed in Microchip Studio

Tags: compilation, atmelstudio

Maybe small but difficult issue for me. Appreciate if someone could lead me to right direction to solve this.

I am trying to build ~10year old files but getting this error is Microchip Studio 7.0.132

C:\test\Makefile(441,1): error: recipe for target 'sizebefore' failed

make: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Mikal/test'

make: *** [sizebefore] Error 255

---

Before error there is also notification that "The system cannot find the path specified"

**Don't understand why it can't find it?**

C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\shellUtils\make.exe -C "C:\Users\Mikal\test" -f "Makefile" all

make: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Mikal/test'

The system cannot find the path specified.

The system cannot find the path specified.

---

***Part of makefile that initiates issue.***

Display size of file.

HEXSIZE = $(SIZE) --target=$(FORMAT) $(TARGET).hex

ELFSIZE = $(SIZE) --mcu=$(MCU) --format=avr $(TARGET).elf

sizebefore:

@if test -f $(TARGET).elf; then echo; echo $(MSG_SIZE_BEFORE); $(ELFSIZE); \

2>/dev/null; echo; fi

sizeafter:

@if test -f $(TARGET).elf; then echo; echo $(MSG_SIZE_AFTER); $(ELFSIZE); \

2>/dev/null; echo; fi

---

**Whole output**

------ Build started: Project: CHB_DIGI, Configuration: Release AVR ------

Build started.

Project "CHB_DIGI.cproj" (default targets):

Target "PreBuildEvent" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(PreBuildEvent)'!='') was evaluated as (''!='').

Target "CoreBuild" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Vs\Compiler.targets" from project "C:\Users\Mikal\test\CHB_DIGI.cproj" (target "Build" depends on it):

Task "RunCompilerTask"

Shell Utils Path C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\shellUtils

C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\shellUtils\make.exe -C "C:\Users\Mikal\test" -f "Makefile" all

make: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Mikal/test'

The system cannot find the path specified.

The system cannot find the path specified.

The system cannot find the path specified.

The system cannot find the path specified.

ECHO is off.

-------- begin --------

avr-gcc (AVR_8_bit_GNU_Toolchain_3.6.2_1778) 5.4.0

Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO

warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

-f was unexpected at this time.

C:\test\Makefile(441,1): error: recipe for target 'sizebefore' failed

make: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Mikal/test'

make: *** [sizebefore] Error 255

Done executing task "RunCompilerTask" -- FAILED.

Done building target "CoreBuild" in project "CHB_DIGI.cproj" -- FAILED.

Done building project "CHB_DIGI.cproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

---

**What i tried**

Tried to comment "sizebefore" away from code. It went further but i faced another issue.
I thought that I should fix the first problem first.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.